# Check if port is open in ANT

Tags: sockets, ant, port, flexunit, flexunit4

Is it possible to check whether a port is open using ANT tasks?

I need to execute flexunit task, but before I start this task I need to check if another flexunit task is not running and blocking the desired port.

Thank you for any suggestions,

Rafal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the ant socket condition.

```
<target name="check-port" description="Check whether Tomcat is running">
    <echo message="Checking whether Tomcat is running"/>
    <condition property="tomcat.running">
      <socket server="${tomcat.host}" port="${tomcat.port}"/> 
    </condition>
</target>
```

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html